# file.path and saving multiple outs to a file

Tags: r, loops, plot, ggplot2, plyr

I have code that is designed to produce multiple output jpeg plots of time series decomposition (in for each hour of the day). I run the code and I do not receive and error. In fact, I receive some indication that the outputs were produced.

Here is the function that was created (given to me from an expert on stackoverflow):

```
HR.plot <- function(y,z){
    ARMAXpath<-file.path("C:", "Desktop","RPLOTS", paste0("HRplot_", z, ".jpg"))
    jpeg(file = ARMAXpath)
    plot(stl(y,s.window="periodic"))
    dev.off()
}
```

I use this code in a by() statement:

```
by(Dataset, Dataset$Hour, function(d) HR.plot(Dataset$UQ,unique(Dataset$Hour)))
```

It returns 1 chart, the very first Hour level and no more.
My question: How can I change the code to get it to produce output plots for eah hour of the day (hour variable)?
I posted a similar question a couple of hours earlier with totally different code and I could not get that code to work, because of issues loading ggplot2
Thank you

Comment: Consider accepting and upvoting the answers to your questions; this is how we give back to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you use `unique(Dataset$Hour)` in your function call instead of using `d`.